# Nodes without "root"

Tags: razor, nodes, categories

I have a question about this code:

```
 @helper  BuildTreeView(IEnumerable<dynamic> data, int? parentid = null, int level = 0) {
    var nodes = data.Where(n => n.ParentId == parentid).OrderBy(n => n.DisplayOrder);
    var aCapo = "";
    if (nodes.Any()) {
        if(nodes.First().ParentId != null){
            level++;
            if (level == 1) {aCapo = "<br>";}
            else if (level >= 2) {aCapo = "&gt;&gt;";}

        }
        foreach (var node in nodes) {
              @Html.Raw(aCapo)  @node.Text           
            @BuildTreeView(data, node.Id, level);
        }
    }
}
```

I would remove "root" so that each category and any subcategories, were not linked to the root.

I would like in practice, this result

`cat1 >> subCat1.a
cat2 >> subCat2.a
cat3 subCat3.a subCat3.b
cat4
cat5 >> subCat5.a`

Comment: I don't see a problem, error or question Luc.

Comment: The problem is that I have a database as follows:

 Id | ParentId | Category

 These are all categories. The "root" I do not want.

 Each category should NOT from the "root"

 I hope I explained.

Comment: Yes, but please explain, what in your code is not working.

Comment: Serv Hello!

the code works perfectly.

The only thing is that I need to populate a select statement. The "root" I do not need.